# Unable to retrieve already exist image uri from firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using isChanged to check if the image is changed if it's changed I'm replacing download uri with the new download URL

```
 downloadUri = task.getResult();
```

if the image is not changed I'm replacing the download uri with existing image uri

`downloadUri= mainImageURI;`

in `storeFirestore()` method but it shows error and the image is not retrieved.

full code of `SettingsActivity.class`:[link](https://usman.sagri.co.in/SettingsActivity.java)

full project:[project file](https://usman.sagri.co.in/pdaceapp/)

Error:[image]

Comment: Please show the logs.

Comment: Please add the error that you get in your logcat and the correspoding line at which it occurs and please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo it says  **error: incompatible types: Uri cannot be converted to UploadTask.TaskSnapshot
** for the code `downloadUri=mainImageURI;` in `public void storeFirestore method` full code: [here](https://usman.sagri.co.in/SettingsActivity.java)

Comment: In this case, please share more code to see the problem more clearly.

Comment: @AlexMamo I've given you link to my java file! https://usman.sagri.co.in/SettingsActivity.java

Comment: @AlexMamo full project link https://usman.sagri.co.in/pdaceapp/

Comment: I see, I'll write you an answer right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

```
incompatible types: Uri cannot be converted to UploadTask.TaskSnapshot ** for the code downloadUri=mainImageURI
```

Because the `downloadUri` object is of type `UploadTask.TaskSnapshot` and you are trying to assign in the following line of code:

```
downloadUri= mainImageURI; // mainImageURI is of type Uri
```

An object of type `Uri`, which cannot be achieved. There is no way in Java to cast an object of type `UploadTask.TaskSnapshot` to `Uri`.

Without knowing the use-case of your app, I can only say that you can solve this, either by changing the type of your `downloadUri` to Uri or to change the type of your `mainImageURI` to `UploadTask.TaskSnapshot`.

Comment: Ok, keep me posted.

Comment: You still get an error, which is? Please add the error or at least a screenshot.

Comment: if I use Uri I am getting an error in the same place but if I use UploadTask.TaskShnapshot I am getting errors in these three places https://usman.sagri.co.in/app-link/errors screenshots are in this folder.

Comment: Yes, that's correct because you are using assigning **again** to that variable an object that cannot be converted to the other object type. You should assign the same object type  in both situations, right?

Comment: what all should i change now?

Comment: In my opinion, you should change the type of the `downloadUri` to `Uri` and assign it the corresponding type of object accordingly (which is not of type UploadTask.TaskSnapshot).

Comment: if I do so I'm getting an error in if part,see images uri7 and uri8 https://usman.sagri.co.in/app-link/errors

Comment: Yes, change the type in all places where you have such an error, right?

Comment: can you please do necessary changes and send me the code

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service. You should definitely make your own attempt given the information in the answer/comments and ask another question if something else comes up.

Comment: bro, even after changing download_uri to Uri I get an error :( error: incompatible types: UploadTask.TaskSnapshot cannot be converted to Uri

Comment: Yes, this is because you are assinging a wrong type of object to the download_uri object. An object of type `UploadTask.TaskSnapshot` will **never** be cast an `Uri` object! Please try to understand this.

Comment: but i have changed download_uri to Uri !!

Comment: It mean that you are trying to do the same thing also in other places in your code. You should change in evrey place.

Comment: Yes because of the incompatibility between object types.